# Emacs equivalent of this Vim command to run my tests?

Tags: vim, emacs

I'm using Emacs at the moment and experimenting with it for my Rails development and there is one thing that I do quite regularly in Vim and I'd like to know if an equivalent exists in Emacs, or an alternative workflow to achieve the behavior that I need.

The command in Vim is

```
:map ;t :!rspec --no-color %<cr>
```

Essentially this maps a key combination to run a bash/shell command on the file represented by the current buffer (`%` expands to the filename at runtime, the `<cr>` is just a carriage return at the end to execute the command).

I map all sorts of random little commands as and when I need them and I really miss the immediacy of this approach.

How can I achieve something similar?

Comment: Do you mean something like [shell-command-on-region](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Single-Shell.html)? You can call this with the whole buffer selected as the region.

Comment: kind of, however in most cases I don't want to run the command on the actual region of test but on the file represented by the buffer. for example `rspec --no-color spec/some_spec.rb`. I love the look of `shell-command-on-region` though – I can definitely see where that would fit in my workflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this function prompts for a command and runs that on to the current buffer file. if no file is associated to current buffer gives an error

```
(defun shell-command-on-buffer-file ()
 "prompts for a command and executes that command on to the associated 
 file of current buffer. if no buffer is associated gives an error"
  (interactive)
  (or (buffer-file-name) (error "no file is associated file to this buffer"))
  (let* ((my-cmd (read-shell-command "Command to run: "))
         (cmd-to-run (concat my-cmd " " (buffer-file-name))))
   (shell-command cmd-to-run)))
```

as usual emacs saves history of commands you have given so far, those can be accessed using M-p,M-n